# Cut string inside "<p></p>"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to convert the text of a p into a string and then edit the text and for that I would use this code:

```
var str = $("p").text();
str = str.replace("|", " ");
$(".post-meta").text(str);
```

This portion of html right now is like this:

```
<p class="post-meta">
  "|"
  "|  0 Comments"
</p>
```

And when i replace the | for a space it will turn out like this:

```
<p class="post-meta"> 
  "0 Comments    |    |  0 Comments         |  0 Comments    |    |  0 Comments"
</p>
```

I don't know if you can understand what i'm asking but i want to replace the text inside the first p tag shown above, and only get the 0 Comments part, keep in mind that I can't just replace the string for "0 Comments" because the number of comments is automatically generated and it will depends on the post.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show a working example of the problem and also the format you want to achieve. I don't see how you're getting the result you describe with the code you've shown

Comment: is there a reason why you added "|" inside the p tag? Wouldn't it be easier to do a before and after content and just get whats in the p tag?

Comment: I'm using wordpress and at first the date, category and the comments were all together in a line so i splitted the three and the format of it was like this date | category | comments, and when i splitted the | kept there, I already improved the code above changing the $("p") to $(this) because i need to refer to the exact tag individually, but it's displaying "| 0 Comments" as well.... it only removed the first "|"... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.replace` with a regular expression:

```
str = str.replace(/\|/g," ");
```

You would normally use `/text/g` where:

- `/` indicates a regex
- `text` is the text to replace
- `g` means all cases (global)

in your case `|` also means something in a regex, so needs to be escaped: `\|`

```js
var str = $("p.post-meta").text();
str = str.replace(/\|/g," ");
$("p.post-meta").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="post-meta">
"|"
"|  0 Comments"
</p>
```

I kept the original with `""` but perhaps you meant to remove them or they were there for illustrative purpose in the question

---

**Update**

To answer the question of why `str.replace(string, ..` only replaces the first occurrance, have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

> **substr (pattern)**
>
> A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. **Only the first occurrence will be replaced.**

(my emphasis).  It doesn't explain *why* though.  Using a regex allows you to add the `/g` to say "all occurrences".

Comment: Thanks, the str.replace part resolved the problem, I wasn't aware of that in jQuery and I will definitely try to understand why that resolves the problem while using "" inside the .replace() doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the more in-depth explanation!